# How to combine 2 numpy.ndarray in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
k=arange(1,100)
m=arange(1,100)
```

Then how to append or combine them into an array with 2 columns and 99 rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vstack`, `hstack` and `transpose` are your friends for things like this.

```
>>> vstack([k,m]).transpose()
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 3,  3],
       ...
       [98, 98],
       [99, 99]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and one further question: if I have a list,  each element of the list is an arrage like k, or m in the original question, then how to make them an arrange?